# How to sort a list that have more than one data in an entry?

Tags: python, sorting

I have this list `data` and need to order it by *Hits*.

```
  data = []
  data.append({"url":"google.com", "Hits":5, "Size":7})
  data.append({"url":"microsoft.com", "Hits":30, "Size":0})
  data.append({"url":"abc.com", "Hits":20, "Size":3})
```

I tried to use `data.sort()` and `sorted(data)` but they aren't working.

Comment: you should add **how** you tried to sort really ...\

Comment: @JoranBeasley ok, as soon as possible I will edit to show the codes I used and the erros I got. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key=` argument to `.sort()` or `sorted()`:

```
data.sort(key=lambda d: d["Hits"])
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the lambda function, you can also pass an `itemgetter` object as the key to `sorted` because instances of `itemgetter` are callable.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(data, key=itemgetter('Hits'))
[{'url': 'google.com', 'Hits': 5, 'Size': 7}, {'url': 'abc.com', 'Hits': 20, 'Size': 3}, {'url': 'microsoft.com', 'Hits': 30, 'Size': 0}]
```